# Stansted airport connection

Tags: short-connections, connecting-flights, stn

I am thinking of buying tickets at a good price. However, the connection time seems really short.

My flights to Stansted will arrive at 14:40. The next flight is at 16:45. Both are from and to EU countries. I am an EU citizen with a red passport.

Does anyone have experience with this particular airport? Will the connection time be enough?

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61137/can-i-make-a-1hr-full-transfer-at-stansted

Answer (score 1):

Stansted is a pretty small airport, with a single terminal.  2 hours should not be a problem, assuming the flights are not significantly delayed.

This assumes you don't have checked-in baggage.  If you do, then it is probably too short as you will have to collect and re-check in.

Comment: I will have only hand luggage :) sounds promising. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it can be called 'pretty small'? It's got three gate zones and a train interconnection.

Comment: Small for a 'hub' airport. It is nothing compared to Heathrow, Amsterdam, Dubai, etc.